# USB to Unique Port for RFID keystrokes

Tags: vb.net, keyboard

This is my first time posting here. I hope you can help me with this guys.

I am trying to use a Generic RFID USB hardware (R10D-USB)in my VB .Net project.

Problem:
It seems that this RFID-USB hardware looks like it is being read by my computer as a Keyboard device. It is producing Keystrokes.

In Device Manager, it is being known as

> Keyboards
>   ----- HID Keyboard Device

also as

> Universal Serial Bus Controllers
>   ----- USB Composite Device

Now, whenever I tap an RFID in the RFID Reader. It produces Keystrokes like Keyboard.

It is typing literally as if your typing on your keyboard. So Whenever I tap an RFID to the RFID reader it would write something even in Notepad.

Concern:
What I am looking for is, is there a way I can sort of like assign it to a Port and only works unless it is being read by my VB form.

in other words, it would stop acting like a keyboard and be disabled to all other programs and activities except the program that I will make to catch all of its Keystrokes (can work on background).

Comment: It looks like HID interface is how that RFID reader works (just like a normal barcode reader) http://alatparkir.info/rfid-reader-r10d-usb-8h10d/

Comment: Yes that's it. However, I want to isolate it's activity so it can capture data on the background so I can use the computer while it is working. If you get what I mean.

Comment: I doubt it is possible unless you can find a different driver for the device.